# can't print '\' (single backslash) in Python

Tags: python

I am using Python 3 and am trying to find a ways to search for a way to insert a '\' (single backslash) into my program.

I am gettin this error:
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Answer (score 3):

You have to escape the backslash:

```
\\
```

From [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

> The backslash `(\)` character is used to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself, or the quote character.

Also, as  @Torxed mentioned in his answer, you can use the prefix `r` or `R`:

> String literals may optionally be prefixed with a letter `'r'` or `'R'`; such strings are called raw strings and use different rules for interpreting backslash escape sequences.

```
r"Some string with \ backslash"
```

Answer (score 3):

or use:

```
print(r'This is \backslash')
```

But escaping with `this \\backslash` is recommended.

Comment: this does not work see it prints `0.60\textbackslash pm0.073` I want `0.60\pm0.073`

Comment: @CharlieParker I think you missunderstood the answer. `print(r"You want 0.60\pm0.073")`. You shouldn't add the string `backslash` there.